# How do you rotate apache logs on windows without interrupting service?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, logging, logrotate

I administrate a Windows Server 2003 (Standard Edition, 32-bit) installation running Apache2 and ColdFusion.  The server has over 100 virtual hosts, each with an access log and an error log. I've been looking for an analog to (or a win32 port of) the classic Linux **[logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/)** command, which allows logfile rotation without interrupting Apache's locking mechanism.

Every solution I've found, including **[chomp](http://chomp.amadis.sytes.net/)**, the conflictingly named **[logrotate](http://iain.cx/src/logrotate/)** bash script, **[apachelogrot](http://www.sprint.net.au/~terbut/usefulbox/apachelogrot.htm)**, and several Perl log rotation scripts; they all:

- stop apache
- rotate the log
- start apache

Obviously, this is not desirable with so many virtual hosts, as it would stop and restart Apache hundreds of times per night.

I have also investigated using **[rotatelogs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/rotatelogs.html)**, which comes with apache, and **[cronolog](http://cronolog.org/)**, which use piped output to create individual daily/weekly/monthly logs.  These programs do not require a restart of apache to rotate the logs, but they spawn an instance of the process for each logfile, resulting in hundreds of additional daemons running, each consuming 200-300k of memory.

I also tried compiling the classic Linux **[logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/)** command on cygwin, but with no luck.

**Do any of you have suggestions about what I should try next?**  Or, even better, have any of you managed to get the classic Linux **[logrotate](https://fedorahosted.org/logrotate/)** command to compile on cygwin, or any other win32 compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, you may be able to switch to use a single log for all virtual hosts and post-process them using [`split-logfile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/programs/split-logfile.html) or something similar (to get them into individual logs per virtual host). This is recommended in Apache's docs [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html#virtualhost). Not sure if it's an  option in your environment.

Comment: That's an excellent suggestion, it may be a possibility.  I'm still looking for the preferred solution though - some program with features closer to the "copytruncate" feature of Linux's rotatelogs utility.

Comment: I think you're going to be stuck with Windows file handling limitations in all cases. I'm definitely interested too if you find a workaround though, so please post back to the thread. :-)

Comment: I've been doing some testing with Perl-logrotate (find it on freshmeat.net).  It looks promising! I'll update the thread when I can confirm that it emulates "copytruncate" to my satisfaction.